# Nothing will unwrap, even after applying seams

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Absolutely nothing will unwrap, on any layer, at all. I have no idea why. The E hotkey doesn't seem to do anything, and neither does pressing the unwrap function its self. I'm at a loss.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose the *UV Editor*, not the *Image Editor*, or choose *Paint* mode instead of *View*. Also, use <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap, not <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: thankyou! I figured it was something very simple, but i couldnt crack the case

Comment: Also you use the 'U' key not 'E' to unwrap!

Comment: oh yes I also saw that